# Perform-replace only on text (no comments, no math) in latex-mode?

Tags: latex, replace, isearch-filter-predicate

I need to write some Emacs-Lisp code that uses the `perform-replace` function, limiting its range of action only on text (ignoring comments, in-line math and math ambients) on LaTeX documents (in `latex-mode`). I'd like to do that in native Emacs. Is there a way to do that without the need for external packages?

Comment: If this is a one-off and the document is relatively short, then I'd do it using an interactive search-and-replace, skipping the things that don't need changing.

Comment: Do you use AUCTeX?  It has facilities to test whether point is in a comment or in math mode.

Comment: @giordano, sorry, I do not use AUCTeX (and I can't...).

Comment: @Nick I'm a professional typesetter so I'm looking for something more powerful of an interactive search-and-replace

Comment: OK, I don't understand the use-case:  you have to do search-and-replace in a lot of documents? Why don't the authors do it right in the first place? Moreover, if you are not the author, why do *you* have to do it?

Comment: @Nick It's my job. I do a lot of replacements on scientific papers to make them fit the layout of the publisher.

Comment: What kind of replacements do you do? I'm having trouble figuring out what would be amenable to an automated script. Can you give some examples?

Comment: @Nick This is the simpliest: "F. S. Surname" --> "F.S.~Surname". But I have very complex replacements to do. Another replacement (of the simple ones) is changing static refs into dynamic: "fig. 3" --> "figure~\ref{fig:3}".

Comment: OK, thanks! That clarifies things a bit. Two more questions if you don't mind: in the "F.S.Surname" case, are you looking for a general pattern (i.e. any surname)? That would be ideal of course, but there is the danger of a spurious match; a set of specific surnames would be safer I think.  Finally, how do you check your output? Diff it with the input?

Comment: @Nick I really know how to do my (query)replacements. I'm just looking a way to skip matches in commented (or math) code for a faster typesetting. `perform-replace` give me the chance to check my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask whether it is possible without an external package. The answer is, "of course" ;-).  Are you also asking someone to give you the code for that here (which is essentially giving you an external package ;-))?  Maybe someone else will provide that info.

---

A short answer is that you can define `isearch-filter-predicate` so that Isearch and `perform-replace` skip matches that are in the areas you want to skip (e.g. comments and whatever else).

---

If you don't mind trying a 3rd-party package, consider [Isearch+](http://www.emacswiki.org/IsearchPlus).  Out of the box you can interactively skip searching comments, and you should be able to do the same for math expressions (whatever they are - you will need to define a suitable predicate).  Then you can use the same filtering that you set up and tested using Isearch to perform replacements (e.g. with `query-replace` or whatever).

For example, during Isearch:

1. **`C-z &`** prompts you for a filter predicate to add.  You can pick a predefined predicate using completion.  One predefined predicate is **`~[;]`**, which means search only *outside comments*.  You do this: `C-z & TAB`, then choose candidate **`~[;]`**, or just do `C-z & ~[;]`.

   The **`~`** in this predicate nickname stands for *not*, the **`[...]`** stands for *inside*, and the **`;`** stands for *comment* (`;` is the comment character for Lisp, so I chose that to stand for "comment").

   You are now searching everywhere **except** in comments.
2. To switch from Isearch to query-replacing, use **`M-%`**.  Since you did this during Isearch the current `isearch-filter-predicate` carries over to replacement: You will be queried for matches only in non-comment zones.

What if you don't switch to query-replace during the same Isearch where you set up the predicate?  When you finish isearching the predicate automatically goes back to what it was before you started using `C-z...`.  But if you use **`C-z s`** before you exit Isearch then the predicate remains as you last defined it.

This means that after step #1 above, you could use `C-z s`, exit Isearch, do something else, and then later use query-replace.  It will pick up that "saved" filter predicate.

(You can use **`C-z 0`** during Isearch to remove your changes to the filter predicate.  You can also toggle to search the *complement* of what the current filter would normally choose.)

You will need to define your own predicates for filtering math zones.  The code in library [`isearch+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el) for defining other filter predicates can help as a model.

The doc describing this on-the-fly defining and using filter predicates is at [Dynamic Isearch Filtering](http://www.emacswiki.org/DynamicIsearchFiltering).

Comment: Thank you. I'm not asking someone to give me the code ;-). I didn't know about `isearch-filter-predicate` so now I have my homework to do. I have to find a way to change that variable in my functions and restore the default value at the end. (I'm not properly a hacker... so this will be a little tricky for me.) Thank you again.

Comment: You can probably just let-bind it. When the let-binding is done the previous value is restored.

Comment: You can use `face-at-point` to recognize and skip comments and formulas (which will have their own faces, I suppose).

Comment: @Elena: That seems like a comment for the question, not for this answer, no?

Comment: Elena is right with a comment complementary to the answer. `face-at-point` is useful when the buffer is already fontified, and when not then better would be to rely on syntax, e.g. `(and comment-start (nth 4 (syntax-ppss)))`.

Comment: @link0ff: That's not complementary to the answer. Whether you use a font-lock face or `syntax-ppss`, the answer applies: use `isearch-filter-predicate` (in both cases). Of course it's possible to not use `isearch-filter-predicate` and instead use code that searches and actively explicitly skips over comments etc. But that is a different answer, and, like this one, it applies to use of both faces and `syntax-ppss`.

Comment: @Drew Based on the documentation I've written a function that can act as a predicate and wanted to add it to the default filter predicates. However, it still doesn't shine up in them. Can you take a look? I do 

`(add-to-list 'isearchp-filter-predicates-alist
      '("[math]" check-math-mode "[MATH]")
      '("~[math]" check-not-math-mode "[MATH]")
      )`

and it shines up on the list but isn't found when I do `C-s C-z & [math]`.

Comment: @AlexanderPraehauser: Comments here aren't the place for this. Send me an email or pose a separate question here. Provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, saying what you see at each step and what you expected to see instead. FWIW, the `add-to-list` sexp you show isn't valid. You need two `add-to-list` calls, to add two elements to the alist.